# Listen to result from event handler in JS

Tags: javascript, events

I have a link in my page `<a href="" onclick="return confirm('...'); " ></a>` and I need to perform some actions if in onclick confirmation was pressed Yes. And because this link is autogenerated I cannot modify it's html. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At runtime, you can replace the click hander:

```js
var element = document.querySelector('a'); // Adjust this selector as necessary
var oldHandler = element.onclick;
element.onclick = function() {
  var rv = oldHandler.apply(this, arguments);
  //...do something with rv...
  alert("The return value was: " + rv);
  return rv;
};
```

```html
<a href="" onclick="return confirm('...'); " >click here</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, seems like it'll work just fine